# .htaccess does not work?

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I'm using Litespeed and clean-urls has been activated.

When I upload .htaccess file, my Drupal does not render links and all link/buttons/drop-down menus expands autttomatically.
When I remove .htaccess, website Works without problem.

*.htaccess is enabled from LiteSpeed configuration.

What is the problem?
How can I use clean-urls?

Comment: Perhaps something wrong with your .htaccess file is my best guess. Can you pastebin it or something so we can take a look. Of course take out any sensitive stuff.

Comment: Hello,

You can see file content from following link;
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9810781/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ... essentially if your content just keeps getting cached by it [litespeed] you will have to keep the compression lines in your .htaccess commented out to prevent the javascript from breaking ...

[Source](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1063958#post7558936)

So essentially he's saying to comment these lines out:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
  RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

  <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
    # Serve correct encoding type.
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
    # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I'm no expert in litespeed either, so I'm not sure if this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps to debug-
1. check if mod_rewrite is enabled on server
2. Check by concatenation if index.php in URL if render page properly. Concatenation of URL will be such as-
http://YOUR-URL.COM/index.php/innerpageroute